# Bootstrap 3 modal that lets users interact with background?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have a Bootstrap 3 modal window that doesn't darken the screen and also lets users interact with the background if they want to? I use the default modal as well so I would want this functionality in addition, not instead of.

I've got an audio player inside a modal window and I'd like usersto be able to scroll the screen behind it (while the modal stays fixed in place) so they can access tracks etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can interact with background then it's not modal.

Instead of a modal it sounds like you want an absolutely positioned div. Check out the "affix" object:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Comment: This is obviously the preferred way to go. If you really want to mess up with modal, look at my proposed solution.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't heard of affix before and this is clearly the way to go.

Comment: FYI "affix" is dropped in bootstrap 4, "sticky" can be used for the same purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You actually should prefer Avibodha's proposal!
But if you really want to use a modal, I've done some first approach here: http://bootply.com/109120

The key steps where:

**disable the grey modal background**
using the backdrop parameter, eg. in the button tag:

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

**shrink the modals container**
such that the underlying element is accessible

```
#myModal {
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Now you can set this modals position with `top` and `left`